# How do you make gettext ALWAYS use a translation instead of default languiage text

Tags: php, gettext

When you call the gettext php function for translating text to another language, it uses the text you have on the page to act as the KEY/ID to lookup the value to replace it with

```
echo gettext('hello how are you today');
```

that would be the text used to lookup the translation,  however I would like to use something like this

```
echo gettext('welcome_message');
```

and have that translated into English and any other language I offer.  So how could I make this happen?  How can I make gettext function ALWAYS use a language file?  So if my default language is English for the site then instead of gettext showing **welcome_message** to an English user it would show **hello how are you today**

Is it as simple as just creating an English language file in addition to the other language files?

Comment: _('text') is the same as doing gettext('text'), there is no need for the lang() function.

Comment: I realize that, i do it for other reason, like sometimes when gettext extension is not available for testing, I can use an array or constants o anyway, it makes my app more flexible.  That is not my question here though

Comment: Also two or three underscores are used as translation function often. This gives even more flexibility like: if there's no built-in gettext extension, just echo the stuff or if flag X is set, read translations from DB etc. Then you just use xgettext --keyword=__. Also Zend_Translate can read gettext strings without the actual PHP extension and has stuff like ->isTranslated() ->hasLanguage('finnish') etc.

Comment: You shouldn't. Gettext has been designed like this for a reason: To provide a default. Of course it will even use an english translation if available, but it will use your useless placeholder for any other language without a translation. No, you are not smarter than gettext developers! Use it the way it meant to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track.  The string argument to gettext() is just an identifier, not a "default language".  If there is no translation in the active locale, then gettext will return that identifier.

Your solution is just what you suspect: just create an English translation file.

Comment: great at first I was thinking it only looked for a language file and translated if the language set was a different language then the site was made it, Like if the site is in English and you are supposed to see spanish then it would get the spanish file but if you were English and viewing the site it would not even bother looking for an English language file but you are saying it will look for the English lang file first before showing the default identifier, awsome +1